# JavaScript cookie setting used to work and stopped

Tags: javascript, cookies

In a nutshell, I have a web application which used to be able to set cookies just fine, but it no longer works. The really strange thing is I've used Chrome's debugger to follow what's going on, and it makes it all the way to the "document.cookie = " statement fine.

Further, I haven't changed anything except the content of the cookie (adding more information). I haven't modified the cookie setting logic at all, or even the parameters.

Here's the most recent version of my application: http://asmor.com/scripts/tsrand/alpha/

The relevant bit is lines 147-149, http://asmor.com/scripts/tsrand/alpha/init.js

```
cookie=JSON.stringify(opt)
log("Cookie: "+cookie);
$.cookie(cookieName, cookie, { expires: 365 });
```

opt is an object I'm using to store form element values. I convert the object into a JSON string and then store it. Here's an example of what cookie contains in this version of the program:

```
{"diseaseSelect":".5","soloGame":"checkbox:false","showLog":"checkbox:true","min_Setting":"0","max_Setting":"1","cardBarrowsdale":"Maybe","cardDoomgate":"Maybe","cardDragonspire":"Maybe","cardDreadwatch":"Maybe","cardFeaynSwamp":"Maybe","cardGrimhold":"Maybe","cardRegianCove":"Maybe","min_Thunderstone":"1","max_Thunderstone":"1","cardStoneofAgony":"Maybe","cardStoneofAvarice":"Maybe","cardStoneofMystery":"Maybe","cardStoneofScorn":"Maybe","cardStoneofTerror":"Maybe","min_Monster":"3","max_Monster":"3","cardAbyssal":"Maybe","cardAbyssalThunderspawn":"Maybe","cardBanditHumanoid":"Maybe","cardCultistHumanoid":"Maybe","cardDarkEnchanted":"Maybe","cardDoomknightHumanoid":"Maybe","cardDragon":"Maybe","cardElementalFire":"Maybe","cardElementalNature":"Maybe","cardElementalPain":"Maybe","cardEnchanted":"Maybe","cardEvilDruidHumanoid":"Maybe","cardGiant":"Maybe","cardGolem":"Maybe","cardHorde":"Maybe","cardHumanoid":"Maybe","cardHydraDragon":"Maybe","cardOoze":"Maybe","cardOrcHumanoid":"Maybe","cardTheSwarm":"Maybe","cardUndeadDoom":"Maybe","cardUndeadLich":"Maybe","cardUndeadPlague":"Maybe","cardUndeadSpirit":"Maybe","cardUndeadStormwraith":"Maybe","min_Guardian":"0","max_Guardian":"1","cardDarkChampion":"Maybe","cardDeathSentinel":"Maybe","cardGuardianofNight":"Maybe","cardGuardianofTorment":"Maybe","cardUnholyGuardian":"Maybe","min_Trap":"0","max_Trap":"1","cardTrapDeath":"Maybe","cardTrapDire":"Maybe","cardTrapDraconic":"Maybe","min_Treasure":"0","max_Treasure":"1","cardAmuletTreasure":"Maybe","cardFigurineTreasure":"Maybe","cardUlbricksTreasure":"Maybe","min_Hero":"4","max_Hero":"4","cardAmazon":"Maybe","cardBelzur":"Maybe","cardBlind":"Maybe","cardCabal":"Maybe","cardChalice":"Maybe","cardChulian":"Maybe","cardClan":"Maybe","cardDeep":"Maybe","cardDiin":"Maybe","cardDrunari":"Maybe","cardDivine":"Maybe","cardDwarf":"Maybe","cardElf":"Maybe","cardEvoker":"Maybe","cardFeayn":"Maybe","cardFlame":"Maybe","cardGangland":"Maybe","cardGohlen":"Maybe","cardGorinth":"Maybe","cardHalf-Orc":"Maybe","cardLorigg":"Maybe","cardOutlands":"Maybe","cardPhalanx":"Maybe","cardRedblade":"Maybe","cardRegian":"Maybe","cardRunespawn":"Maybe","cardSelurin":"Maybe","cardSidhe":"Maybe","cardSlynn":"Maybe","cardStoneguard":"Maybe","cardTempest":"Maybe","cardTerakian":"Maybe","cardTholis":"Maybe","cardThyrian":"Maybe","cardToryn":"Maybe","cardVerdan":"Maybe","cardVeteran":"Maybe","min_Village":"8","max_Village":"8","cardAmbrosia":"Maybe","cardAmuletofPower":"Maybe","cardArcaneEnergies":"Maybe","cardBanish":"Maybe","cardBarkeep":"Maybe","cardBattleFury":"Maybe","cardBlacksmith":"Maybe","cardBlessedHammer":"Maybe","cardBluefireStaff":"Maybe","cardBorderGuard":"Maybe","cardBurntOffering":"Maybe","cardChieftansDrum":"Maybe","cardClaymore":"Maybe","cardCreepingDeath":"Maybe","cardCursedMace":"Maybe","cardCyclone":"Maybe","cardDivineStaff":"Maybe","cardDoomgateSquire":"Maybe","cardFeast":"Maybe","cardFireball":"Maybe","cardFlamingSword":"Maybe","cardFlaskofOil":"Maybe","cardForesightElixir":"Maybe","cardFortuneTeller":"Maybe","cardFrostBolt":"Maybe","cardFrostGiantAxe":"Maybe","cardGlowberries":"Maybe","cardGoodberries":"Maybe","cardGreedBlade":"Maybe","cardGuardianBlade":"Maybe","cardGuide":"Maybe","cardHatchet":"Maybe","cardIllusoryBlade":"Maybe","cardLantern":"Maybe","cardLightstoneGem":"Maybe","cardMagiStaff":"Maybe","cardMagicMissile":"Maybe","cardMagicalAura":"Maybe","cardPawnbroker":"Maybe","cardPiousChampion":"Maybe","cardPolearm":"Maybe","cardPolymorph":"Maybe","cardQuartermaster":"Maybe","cardRecurveBow":"Maybe","cardSage":"Maybe","cardScout":"Maybe","cardShortBow":"Maybe","cardShortSword":"Maybe","cardSilverstorm":"Maybe","cardSkullbreaker":"Maybe","cardSoulGem":"Maybe","cardSoulJar":"Maybe","cardSpear":"Maybe","cardSpiritBlast":"Maybe","cardSpiritHunter":"Maybe","cardSpoiledFood":"Maybe","cardTavernBrawl":"Maybe","cardTaxCollector":"Maybe","cardThunderRing":"Maybe","cardTorynGauntlet":"Maybe","cardTownGuard":"Maybe","cardTrader":"Maybe","cardTrainer":"Maybe","cardWarhammer":"Maybe"}
```

Now, here's the oldest backed-up copy I have: http://asmor.com/scripts/tsrand/backup/2010-09-13/dev/

This copy still works.

Here's the cookie-setting logic from that copy, lines 130-132 http://asmor.com/scripts/tsrand/backup/2010-09-13/dev/scripts/init.js

```
cookie=JSON.stringify(opt)
log("Cookie: "+cookie);
$.cookie(cookieName, cookie, { expires: 365 });
```

And an example of what the cookie for that one contains:

```
{"guardianSelect":".5","trapSelect":"1","monstersSelect":"3","heroesSelect":"4","villageSelect":"8","soloGame":"checkbox:false","useConditions":"checkbox:true","showLog":"checkbox:true","setBase":"checkbox:false","setPromo":"checkbox:true","setWrathOfTheElements":"checkbox:false","cardAbyssal":"Maybe","cardDoomknightHumanoid":"Maybe","cardDragon":"Maybe","cardElementalNature":"Maybe","cardElementalPain":"Maybe","cardEnchanted":"Maybe","cardGolem":"Maybe","cardHorde":"Maybe","cardHumanoid":"Maybe","cardOoze":"Maybe","cardUndeadDoom":"Maybe","cardUndeadSpirit":"Maybe","cardDarkChampion":"Maybe","cardDeathSentinel":"Maybe","cardTrapDeath":"Maybe","cardTrapDire":"Maybe","cardAmazon":"Maybe","cardBlind":"Maybe","cardChalice":"Maybe","cardClan":"Maybe","cardDiin":"Maybe","cardDivine":"Maybe","cardDwarf":"Maybe","cardElf":"Maybe","cardFeayn":"Maybe","cardGangland":"Maybe","cardGohlen":"Maybe","cardLorigg":"Maybe","cardOutlands":"Maybe","cardRedblade":"Maybe","cardRegian":"Maybe","cardRunespawn":"Maybe","cardSelurin":"Maybe","cardThyrian":"Maybe","cardToryn":"Maybe","cardAmbrosia":"Maybe","cardAmuletofPower":"Maybe","cardArcaneEnergies":"Maybe","cardBanish":"Maybe","cardBarkeep":"Maybe","cardBattleFury":"Maybe","cardBlacksmith":"Maybe","cardClaymore":"Maybe","cardCreepingDeath":"Maybe","cardCursedMace":"Maybe","cardFeast":"Maybe","cardFireball":"Maybe","cardFlamingSword":"Maybe","cardForesightElixir":"Maybe","cardGoodberries":"Maybe","cardHatchet":"Maybe","cardIllusoryBlade":"Maybe","cardLantern":"Maybe","cardLightstoneGem":"Maybe","cardMagiStaff":"Maybe","cardMagicMissile":"Maybe","cardMagicalAura":"Maybe","cardPawnbroker":"Maybe","cardPolearm":"Maybe","cardSage":"Maybe","cardShortBow":"Maybe","cardShortSword":"Maybe","cardSpear":"Maybe","cardTavernBrawl":"Maybe","cardTaxCollector":"Maybe","cardTownGuard":"Maybe","cardTrainer":"Maybe","cardWarhammer":"Maybe"}
```

I'm using libraries for the JSON and for setting/getting the cookie. Both that early version and the latest use the exact same versions of the exact same libraries.

The only thing I can think of is that the cookie has gotten a bit more than twice as long. Before URI encoding, we're talking 4000 characters vs. 1800 characters. Also, I URI encoded the more recent cookie and manually set it myself, and the browser accepted it just fine, and my program loaded it just fine.

I'm completely out of ideas here. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really store all this data in a session on the server if possible, rather than having a massive cookie. Then you can simply request data via AJAX or embed it in each page request.

Browsers are only required to provide 4KB of space per cookie, so if you're over that there's a chance it might not be stored.

Comment: Ah... so it most likely is a size limit, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

4096-byte limit; otherwise entire cookie is discarded by IE.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070